# PHP 'Call to undefined function' across two different includes?

Tags: php, html

I've got four PHP files that will form a simple template for my website:
- **functions.php** (with all of the main functions for the website - huge file)
- **index.php** (the main template file I'll be using, that will bring together the other three documents)
- **header.php** (header for the website) 
- **footer.php** (footer for the website - ***this is where the problem occurs***)

**functions.php** - a snippet. This function is simply on its own, not inside of a class or anything.

```
<?php
function LandingPageURL($Phrase, $LPID){
$LandingPageURL = "https://www.website.com/" . trim(strtolower(str_replace("d'","",str_replace(" ", "-", $Phrase)))) . "-" . trim($LPID) . "/";
}
?>
```

**header.php** - no relevant parts. But, I am able to use functions from the functions.php file fine from here.

**footer.php** - relevant parts included. Error occurs here on line 27.

```
echo '<li><a href="' . LandingPageURL($ar_CHANNELS[$ar_CHANNELS_POS][$v_CH_PHRASE],$ar_CHANNELS[$ar_CHANNELS_POS][$v_CH_LPID])
```

The $ar_CHANNELS* variables are simply values from an array that I have.

**index.php** - relevant parts included. 
This is included at the top of the file:

```
<?php
require ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/" . "resources/nw/lib/includes/functions.php");
?>
```

This definitely works as I am calling other variables from functions.php, which are successful.

 Further down the file, I include first the header.php file, then the footer.php file in identical ways:

```
require ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/" . "page/page-elements/header.php");
require ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/" . "page/page-elements/footer.php");
```

When the footer.php is included, and I load the webpage, I get the error message:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function LandingPageURL() in C:\Hosting\website\httpdocs\page\page-elements\footer.php on line 27

Is it something that I'm doing wrong, calling a function from another file that is included into my main index.php file? I made sure to use 'require', so that I knew that functions.php was being pulled into the index.php.

Comment: where is the balance code echo '<li><a href="' . LandingPageURL($ar_CHANNELS[$ar_CHANNELS_POS][$v_CH_PHRASE],$ar_CHANNELS[$ar_CHANNELS_POS][$v_CH_LPID])..?

Comment: Have you tried putting `require_once 'functions.php'` in footer.php? Since you're calling a function which is located in functions.php, it should be included

Comment: @Error404 - I didn't include because it wasn't relevant and didn't want to make the post larger than it already is

Comment: The footer.php file is included in the index.php file which already has the functions.php included. And if I add functions.php to footer.php, it throws an error about a function already being declared.

Comment: @Cawley Can you create a minimal, complete verifiable example in which the error occurs? Remove all unrelated code, or create 3 files with functions that contain just print statements

Comment: @Frank Worked absolutely fine in minified format. The problem isn't the function (as it does work), the problem is that having a call to the function from another includes just doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Cawley, I ran the code you just posted and no errors occurred. Just make sure all the function/file names/parameters are correct. Otherwise, the errors is somewhere else in your code, I guess

Comment: @Frank, did you run the code in one document or did you try separating into multiple files (e.g. separate functions, header and footer?)

Comment: @Cawley, I split into multiple files

Answer (score 0):

Rather embarrassingly, the whole problem was caused by not properly closing a preceding function.

Answer (score -1):

The `functipns.php` file has to be included inside `footer.php` if you want to use its functions there.

Comment: "This definitely works as I am calling other variables from functions.php, which are successful. "

Comment: If it's working for other functions, just copy a function that's working and transform it line by line to the function you want it to be and report at which step the error occurs

Comment: Any more suggestions? I can use functions in the header.php file, which is also included from the index.php file